# Kill MongoDB Server - Windows 7

Tags: mongodb, windows-7, cmd

I just fired up `mongod.exe` for my first time. However, I accidentally closed the command prompt and now I can't figure out how to kill the DB server process. I tried connecting via `mongo.exe` but I'm getting following error:

`exception: connect failed`

How do I stop the server process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you started `mongod.exe` via a command prompt in Windows:

```
> mongod
```

And then you closed that command window, the process will automatically be terminated. It is not running any more.

The error you're receiving when running `mongo.exe` is because MongoDB is not running.  You'll need to run `mongod.exe` again if you need to access the database with the console via `mongo.exe`

You may want to consider setting MongoDB up as a [service](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-windows/) on Windows.

Comment: On running 'mongod.exe' again, I'm getting the following error msg: 'unable to create/open lock file: ...mongod.lock Access is denied. Is a mongod instance already running?, terminating'

Comment: Just go to the database directory and delete the mongod.lock would do the trick. It's because your mongod.exe is terminated abnormally. Next time you can use Ctrl+C to end the mongod process to avoid this problem from happening again.